# Cypress run command throwing TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'trim') on only one machine

Tags: cypress, headless

Hi have problem with cypress run, it stopped working on my machine. Same code working on other VMs perfectly. When using cypress open and work through UI it works without problems.
Console log:

```
npx cypress run --spec "cypress/e2e/Tests/Login/*"


DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:53549/devtools/browser/8b964c55-5a77-49e6-94b7-e58fcedc1120
Couldn't determine Mocha version
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'trim')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'trim')
    at <embedded>:2885:32196
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
    at Object.parseTable (<embedded>:2885:32183)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (<embedded>:2885:36843)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
    at Process.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "cypress",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "cypress": "^12.17.4",
    "eslint": "^8.35.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^17.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.27.5",
    "eslint-plugin-n": "^15.6.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^6.1.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "dayjs": "^1.11.7",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.12.1"
  }
}
```

cypress.config.js

```
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')

const pageLoadTimeoutMiliseconds = 100000

module.exports = defineConfig({
  pageLoadTimeout: pageLoadTimeoutMiliseconds,
  chromeWebSecurity: false,
  reporter: 'junit',
  reporterOptions: {
    mochaFile: 'results/test-output.xml',
    toConsole: true
  },
  e2e: {
    experimentalModifyObstructiveThirdPartyCode: true,
    modifyObstructiveCode: true,

    baseUrl: 'site url',
    setupNodeEvents
    (on, config) {}
  }
})
```

Tried under Node 16, 18 and 20, still no luck what I'm missing here. It has started to occurs when I was playing with reporters but removing reporter config don't help and still have this error.

Test code:

```
import HomePage from '../../Pages/HomePage'
const homePage = new HomePage()

before('Clean all session storage/cache', () => {
  cy.clearAllSessionStorage()
  cy.clearAllLocalStorage()
  cy.clearAllCookies()
  cy.loginToAAD(Cypress.env('aad_username'), Cypress.env('aad_password'))
})

afterEach(() => {
  Cypress.session.clearAllSavedSessions()
})

describe('User can successfully log into the application', () => {
  it('Verifies the user logged in has the correct name', () => {
    homePage.visitHomePage()
    cy.wait(12000)
    homePage.getUserName().should('contain', Cypress.env('username'))
  })
})
```

```
class HomePage {
  visitHomePage () {
    return cy.visit('/')
  }

  getUserName () {
    return cy.get('.header>h2')
  }
}

export default HomePage
```

Comment: where's your code with trim() ?

Comment: I've added tests that are running. The problem is that there is no trim. This code is working on other machines both headles and UI mode.

Comment: Its before even entering the running tests.